# What is the difference between window and winclass in Silktest?

Tags: silktest

What is the difference between window and winclass in Silktest? I find both to be similiar. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A window is an instance of winclass.

in the [Silktest Documentation here is what it says about winclass](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.borland.silktest.classic.doc%2FSTCLASSIC-BC7AF8F5-WINCLASSDECLARATION-REF.html) under that Action Heading

> Declares a window class for an application-specific window or control.